# Source for abrah kadabrah

Tags: sources-mekorot, language, words

I remember seeing a passuk that has the phrase "abrah kadabrah," or maybe a Rishon. Does anyone know a source?

Comment: I don't know a specific pasuk where this phrase is used, but the phrase could very plausibly come from Hebrew. Translated, it would be something along the lines of "I will create as I say." That strongly hints of Hashem's creation of the world.

Comment: I know the def and idea just forgot source ,saw it a few years ago dont rem where.

Comment: It's in the Talmud. But it's not written exactly. It's more like Adbaraha K'davarah. It's not in tanach, just the Talmud and maybe Midrashim.

Comment: Source please ?

Comment: Abra kadabrah, I had heard, is a transliteration of the Hebrew words אברא, I will create, and כדברא, with speech. Similarly, the Harry Potter spell "Avada kedabra" is אבדא, I will destroy, כדברא, with speech.

Answer (score 5):

I searched the [Bar-Ilan books](http://www.responsa.co.il/default.aspx?action=advancedSearch!yes). There are no results.

Craig Conley ([*Magic Words* p. 66](http://books.google.com/books?id=3SB60Wavy6MC&pg=PA66#v=onepage&q&f=false)) writes:

> More popularly, *abracadabra* is associated with a Hebrew-Aramaic expression, variously transliterated: *ibra k'dibra* ("I create through my speech"[49]) ... *Abra kadavra* ("I will create with words"[51]).
>
> [49] Estelle Frankel, *Sacred Therapy: Jewish Spiritual Teachings on Emotional Healing and Inner Wholeness* (2004)
>
> [51] David Aaron, *Endless Light: The Ancient Path of Kabbalah* (1998)

Comment: There is a jewish source I saw it inside.

Comment: @sam Evidently not one included in the Bar-Ilan collection.

Comment: @sam It's in the Talmud.  But it's not written exactly. It's more like Adbaraha K'davarah.  It's not in tanach, just the Talmud and maybe Midrashim.

Answer (score 0):

I remember reading it in Sefer Heyetzirah, the one with Aryeh Kaplan's peirush.

Comment: Rivka, welcome to Mi Yodeya! If you could indicate where exactly in Sefer Hayetzirah you saw this phrase that would greatly increase the value of your answer.

Comment: It seems not to be in [the short version](http://www.psyche.com/psyche/txt/kaplan_sy_short.html). Maybe there is a long version that does have it.